# Свернуть часть сообщения в telegram боте

Tags: python, telegram, бот, sendmessage

Можно ли при отправки большого сообщения от бота (бот на python), свернуть его, чтобы увидеть его полностью пользователь должен нажать далее (к примеру)?

Вот в такой конструкции можно ли такое провернуть:

```
await bot.send_message(...)
```

Comment: Разве в телеграме можно сворачивать сообщение?

Comment: Делаете 2 переменные: 1ая для части сообщения, 2ую для полного сообщения. В нужных местах их используете

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
item = types.KeyboardButton("ДАЛЕЕ")
markup.add(item)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Howdy, how are you doing?", reply_markup=markup)

    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "ДАЛЕЕ" and message.chat.type == 'private')
    def answer(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "I`m ok. And you?")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```